# Como liberar acesso ao MySQL in-app na Azure?

Tags: microsoft-azure

Tenho um aplicativo web na plataforma Azure, este aplicativo tem um MySQL "embutido", ou seja, incluindo dentro do próprio aplicativo.

Gostaria de saber se consigo liberar conexão externa a este banco de alguma forma. Referência: https://www.eliostruyf.com/moving-your-database-to-the-mysql-in-app-option-in-azure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NÃO.

Não tem como vc, diretamente, acessar um MySQL In App. Esse é um serviço para criar protótipos, te oferecendo um serviço de hospedagem simples e barato - pois não cobra excedentes pelo banco. A própria [Microsoft diz que não é recomendada para aplicações de produção](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/mysql-in-app-preview-app-service/).

Para gerencia esse banco, apenas usando o PhpMyAdmin, que pode ser acessado via Portal Azure / WebApp / MySQL In App / Manage.

[image: Azure WebApp - MySQL In App - MySQL Manage]